# Universal links not working when activated from a browser

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-universal-links

I have a flutter app for both Android and iOS. The app supports universal links. It's supposed to open the app when the user taps on the account activation link it received by email which looks like this: `https://my-domain.com/auth/create-password?token=authtoken`. Everything works perfectly on the simulator. It also works correctly on the physical device if the user taps on the link from the mail or notes app. However, when tapped on from the safari or chrome browser the link opens in that browser instead of my app.

My aasa file is served from `https://my-domain.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` and looks like this:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [
                    "my_team_id.com.mydomain.app.name"
                ],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "/auth/create-password*",
                        "comment": "Password creation"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have added the associated domains entitlement to my app and the `Runner.entitlements` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
 <array>
  <string>applinks:my-domain.com</string>
 </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Also I have this line in my `Info.plist`:

```
<key>FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

Are universal links even expected to work when activated from the browser? I can't find any solid information about that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Universal links are expected to work when activated from the browser. [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing-apps-and-websites-to-link-to-your-content) states:

> With universal links, users open your app when they click links to your website within Safari and WKWebView

However, there are certain caveats. First, if an app uses some of the methods described in the documentation, then that link will not open in the app. The documentation states:

> **Note**
>
> If your app uses one of the above methods to open a universal link to your website, the link won’t open in your app.

You can refer to the list of methods on the documentation page, but the one that will most likely matter in your context is [`open(_:options:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open)

This is most likely not what is happening in your case.

Second caveat is that if you are on the same domain as your universal links (probably browsing your website) and click a link from there, the universal link will not be triggered. To quote the documentation:

> When a user browses your website in Safari and taps a universal link in the same domain, the system opens that link in Safari, respecting the user’s most likely intent to continue within the browser. If the user taps a universal link in a different domain, the system opens the link in your app.

You would easily be able to determine if this is what is causing the issue in your case.

Lastly, there is a behaviour where the system remembers if you open a universal link, the system launches your app, and then you use the back to safari button in the status bar, then the next time the system will not trigger that universal link.

This is mentioned in [the old documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) but I think it is still relevant and accurate. The (old) documentation states:

> When a user taps a universal link that you handle, iOS also examines the user’s recent choices to determine whether to open your app or your website. For example, a user who has tapped a universal link to open your app can later choose to open your website in Safari by tapping a breadcrumb button in the status bar. After the user makes this choice, iOS continues to open your website in Safari until the user chooses to open your app by tapping OPEN in the Smart App Banner on the webpage.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The links started to work without any apparent changes. I can't quite trace what helped, but your answer was helpful and very comprehensive so I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: The bottom section, about the ’breadcrumb button in the status bar’ overriding universal link opening, doesn’t seem to be valid anymore? At least not in iOS 17. Otherwise it should be reproducible by opening the app from a browser, then tapping the breadcrumb button. A consecutive attempt to open the universal link should then not open in the app. Which isn’t what happens for me.